# how can I add more stack with main args?

Tags: c++, c, stack

I am trying to add more stack into the my program , but however my program uses main with arguments, but I need to use main with args for testing porpuses , but how can I add use `_declspec` with args in this case? I am adding more stack because I am creating some content for security issues, but I cannot show up full experimet without limit me with stack

```
_declspec(noinline) int old_main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s examlpe", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    char buf[MAX_BUFFER];
    strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
    printf("%s hi!\n", buf);
}

int main() {
    char moreStack[10000];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(moreStack); ++i)
        moreStack[i] = i;

    return old_main();
}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you're trying to do. What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to "add more stack"?

Comment: I want to stack more stack to my program because I am doing some security experiments

Comment: I can't figure this out: "My program uses main with arguments, but I need to use main with args for testing purposes." You have X, but you want to use X. So problem is solved? Depending on the operating system, there may be ways to configure stack size. But in this case, there's no obvious reason why `moreStack` needs to be a stack variable at all. Just make it a global variable or a static local.

Comment: I still don't follow. Do you want to allocate your own stack and then switch to that stack? Is your real question "How do I switch to using a stack that I allocated?"

Comment: @DavidSchwartz exactly

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way to do this is as follows:

1. Save `argc` and `argv` to global variables.
2. Create a `pthread_attr_t` object and call `pthread_attr_setstacksize` to set the stack size you want.
3. Call `pthread_create` using the `pthread_attr_t` you set up to create a detached thread to run a function that passes the global saved `argc` and `argv` values to the `old_main` function.
4. Call `pthread_exit` to terminate the original thread.
5. The newly-created thread goes on executing `old_main` with a stack of the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows and MSVC as the compiler, what you appear to be looking for is the [/F compiler flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=vs-2019) or the [/STACK linker flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations?view=vs-2019). Either one will adjust the stack size of your executable's main thread.

Answer (score -1):

if you want more stack, there may be an option when linking the executable.